# JSON to multiple DataFrames with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_id": "11decadd",
      "name": "Com",
      "category_type": "Type",
      "position": 5,
      "vela_defined": True,
      "created_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700"
    },
    {
      "category_id": "c7010763",
      "name": "none",
      "category_type": "EquipmentStatus",
      "position": 1,
      "vela_defined": True,
      "created_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-01 04:20:38 -0700"
    }
  ],
  "customizable_categories": [
    {
      "customizable_category_id": "435ae18b",
      "name": "NA",
      "category_id": "11decadd",
      "position": 1,
      "created_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700"
    },
    {
      "customizable_category_id": "51e607d8",
      "name": "Third Party",
      "category_id": "fafab667",
      "position": 2,
      "created_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700"
    }
  ],
  "equipment_category_status_sets": [

  ]
}
```

and Im attempting to turn it into 3x Pandas data frames (as named by the JSON top level entry)

But cant seem to get it to load at all. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` contructor for `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print (dfs['categories'])

  category_id     ...      vela_defined
0    11decadd     ...              True
1    c7010763     ...              True

[2 rows x 7 columns]

print (dfs['customizable_categories'])

  category_id            ...                             updated_at
0    11decadd            ...              2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700
1    fafab667            ...              2017-02-15 01:49:23 -0700

[2 rows x 6 columns]

print (dfs['equipment_category_status_sets'])

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```